# Why does the popular algorithm for for expressing the field extension F(a) as a vector space actually produce the correct answer?

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

When asked to describe the field extension F(a), where F is a subfield of E and a is an element of E, many people instinctively respond with the following algorithm: they generate (in E) the sequence $a, a^2, a^3, ...$ , stopping at the first $a^n$ that results in a set of n elements that are closed under multiplication. Then they assert that the vector space ${c_0 + c_1a + c_2a^2 + ... + c_na^n}$ is not only a vector space but also a field and assert that this field is the smallest subfield of E that contains a.

I have a hunch this algorithm is correct but I am asking how to prove it is correct. All I know for sure is that F(a) is isomorphic to F[x]/<p> where p is the minimal polynomial of a in F[x]. Is there some way to prove this algorithm does always produce the same result, something isomorphic to F[x]/<p> where p is the minimal polynomial of a in F[x]? Or even that this algorithm does, indeed always produce a field at all and not just a vector space that is not a field? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indeed follows from $F(a)\cong F[x]/(p)$. Let's say $p=a_nx^n+\ldots+a_0$ with $a_i\in F$ for all $i$. Then (in $F[x]/(p)$) you can express $x^n$ as a linear combination of $\{1,x,x^2\dots x^{n-1}\}$ by as follows (note that in $F[x]/(p)$, you identify $p$ with $0$):
$$x^n = x^n - a_n^{-1}p = -a_n^{-1}a_{n-1}x^{n-1}-\ldots-a_n^{-1}a_0$$

More generally if $N\geq n$:

$$x^N=x^N-a_n^{-1}px^{N-n}$$

reduces the degree by at least $1$ and you can just keep doing that until everything is in linear combination of $\{1,x,x^2\dots x^{n-1}\}$ since the degree decreases every step. Now note that the isomorphism from $F[x]/(p)$ to $F(a)$ maps $x\to a$, meaning $\{1,a,a^2\dots a^{n-1}\}$ will be the basis for $F(a)$.

Comment: I think you just proved that if any polynomial in F[x] is divided by a polynomial of degree n, the remainder will be a polynomial of degree n-1 or less. Or more specifically, that every coset in F[x]/<p>, where deg(p)=n, can be represented by a polynomial of degree n-1 or less.

Getting back to the algorithm, Would agree that when people see F(a) and immediately start generating the sequence ($a, a^2, a^3, ...$) they are actually first deciding that a looks like it's algebraic? And when they start generating the sequence they expect to be able to stop after n-1 elements where n=deg(p)?

Comment: The field F(a) is {f(a)/g(a) | f, g $\in$ F[x] and g(a)$\neq$0}. The vector space we construct is {$c_na^n + c_{n-1}a^{n-1} ... + c_0 | c_i \in F$}. How can we prove that that field and that vector space are actually isomorphic, especially since the vector space seems as though it might be a lot smaller than the field and also since it isn't exactly clear that the vector space is even a field at all? Most people seem to take it as obvious the field and the vector space are isomorphic; my real question is what makes that so obvious to everyone?

Comment: Everything you ask follows from the fact that there exists an isomorphism from $F[x]/(p)$ to $F(a)$ that sends $F$ to itself and $x$ to $\alpha$ and since $F[x]/(p)$ is a vectorspace over $F$ with basis $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots x^{n-1}\}$ which you can check by checking the axioms. (note that the basis also includes $1$, you seemed to forget that in your posts)

Comment: I said they would generate the sequence {a,a^2…} and stop after n-1 elements. That's where the 1 you are looking for was hidden. I know I haven't explained my question very well yet. Let me start with this. Do we agree that F(a) must always contain, for example, (a^19 - 7a^3)/(a^4 + 3a+28)? I am a student and I am asking for help to know what the mapping is from that field element to an element in the vector space people instinctively create.

Comment: Ah yes understand. First you find the inverse of $a^4+3a+28$ by multiplying it with $b_0+b_1x+\ldots+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}$ and finding what the values of $b_i$ have to be so the product is $1$, then you can use that to rewrite the equation so it doesn't have a fraction anymore but is the product of polynomials, you can write that in function of $\{1,a\dots a^{n-1}\}$. When you now change $a\to x$ you get the corresponding element of $F[x]/(p)$

Comment: You are sure that inverse exists as a polynomial because $F[x]/(p)\cong F(a)$ and $F(a)$ is a field meaning that inverse has to exist as well in $F[x]/(p)$ and those are all polynomials.

Comment: Thank you; that is what I needed! I suppose I could even multiply $a^4+3a+28$ by $b_0+b_1a+…+b_{n−1}a^{n−1}$ with a's rather than x's and then use p to reduce the degree to n-1 or less. Thank you again!